# Finding minimum value using count and then finding out what that count is

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get the minimum value out of my Inv variables.. This works however I thought i might be able to add i=y  to the end of the If Tmp... statement so once it applies to Tmp < Fun it can set the i count to y and then i can go around later and use (Inv(y)) object later.. not sure if this will work it just makes sense in my head right now. Summarizing my question... why is msgbox y in the end giving me a value of 0 even though i is not. Any feedback would be great, thank you very much in advance

```
Dim Fun As Variant
Dim Tmp As Variant
Dim Inv() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim y As Integer

Inv = Split("NBInv NEBInv EBInv SEBInv SBInv SWBInv WBInv NWBInv")
Fun = 1000

For i = 0 To UBound(Inv)
    Tmp = Val(ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(Inv(i)).Object.Value)
    If Tmp <> 0 And Tmp <> "" And Tmp < Fun Then Fun = Tmp And i = y
Next i

Smallest = Fun
MsgBox y
```

Comment: `y` is 0 at the end because you never set `y` to anything - so it just gives default value of `0`.

Comment: "Then Fun = Tmp And i = y" i tried y = i as well but it still gives me 0. is that not setting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's split your `If` statement up and see what it actually ***does***:

Pull the conditional expression into its block:

```
If Tmp <> 0 And Tmp <> "" And Tmp < Fun Then 
    Fun = Tmp And i = y
End If
```

Add the implicit parentheses to the right of the assignment:

```
If Tmp <> 0 And Tmp <> "" And Tmp < Fun Then 
    Fun = (Tmp And i = y)
End If
```

Add the implicit parentheses to the right of the `And`:

```
If Tmp <> 0 And Tmp <> "" And Tmp < Fun Then 
    Fun = (Tmp And (i = y))
End If
```

Now look at the expression `i = y` - since it's on the *right-hand side*, this evaluates as a `Boolean`, so it's either `0` or `-1` when cast to a number.  Let's assume that it's `0` and put it back into the expression:  `Temp And 0`.  This is performing a *binary And operation*.  You then assign the result to `Temp`.  That's the only thing that gets set.

I'm *guessing* your intention was this...

```
If Tmp <> 0 And Tmp <> "" And Tmp < Fun Then 
    Fun = Tmp 
    i = y
End If
```

...although assigning to your loop counter is a bad idea.